# Is a question about terminal behavior on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic, scope

I was about to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349324/can-i-turn-off-terminal-case-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-12-10) about modifying terminal behaviour as off-topic because I thought it really belonged at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), since the issue actually applies more generally to Linux). But then I thought maybe it is actually [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, as the Linux terminal could be considered a "software tool commonly used by programmers". Is such a question on-topic or not, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that question is off-topic, but it's too old to migrate to another site so I just closed it.

The Linux terminal could be considered a "software tool commonly used by programmers," but it is by no means *primarily* a programming tool, and I don't see any evidence in that question that the author was using it for programming. It would have been better asked on Ubuntu or Unix & Linux as you suggested.

Comment: Indeed, now I see in the Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic menu: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". Perhaps the [relevant Help Center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) could be updated to be more clear and also consistent with what's mentioned in the flagging menu.